# dask mro Error due to transition from Windows to Linux

Tags: python, linux, dask, method-resolution-order

I've build a Python 2.7 code using `dask` package `delayed` and `compute` methods.

Here is a tiny example of my code:

```
from dask import delayed, compute
import time

class simulation():
   # defines simulation parameters
   def __init__(self,x):
        self.x = x

jobs = range(50) # sample jobs

def simulate(sim):
    # sample simulation function
    time.sleep(0.01*sim.x)
    return sim.x**2

def save_results(results):
    # sample dump results function
    print results
    return []

results = []
for i,j in enumerate(jobs) :
    sim = simulation(j)
    res  = delayed(simulate)(sim) # running simulation given input params as job
    results.append(res)
    if i%10==0 or i==len(jobs)-1: # evaluation every 50 steps
        results  = compute(results)[0] # dask execution
        results  = save_results(results) # storing results to DB and returning empty list
```

for some reason this code runs perfectly on anaconda setup on windows, but fails on Linux.

The error I get is:

> ```
> --> 134          res  = delayed(simulate)(simulation)
>     135 
>     136
> ```
>
> ...
>
> ```
> /home/user/.conda/envs/neuro/lib/python2.7/abc.pyc in __subclasscheck__(cls, subclass)
>     159             return False
>     160         # Check the subclass hook
> --> 161         ok = cls.__subclasshook__(subclass)
>     162         if ok is not NotImplemented:
>     163             assert isinstance(ok, bool)
>
> /home/user/.conda/envs/neuro/lib/python2.7/site-packages/backports_abc.pyc
>
>  in __subclasshook__(cls, C)
>      64         def __subclasshook__(cls, C):
>      65             if cls is Generator:
> ---> 66                 mro = C.__mro__
>      67                 for method in required_methods:
>      68                     for base in mro:
>
> AttributeError: class simulation has no attribute '__mro__'
> ```

Updating packages (`dask`) to the latest version didn't help.

Any suggestion on how to fix it?

Thanks

Comment: Are you able to provide a full [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that others can copy-paste to reproduce the error?

Comment: My python code is a minimal reproducible example. The original one is 20 times longer. As for the error - apparently on linux there is ``__mro__``  check, which is no compatible with my class (but only on ``dask``). Defining the class with ``class simulation(object)`` will solve it (I just can't post an answer myself yet)

Comment: When I copy your code it can't find the `simulate` function or the `jobs` variable

Comment: You're right  :) - I've edited and now the sample is a fully working code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, since `dask` trying to parallelize the execution of commands, it needs to build a dependency path between tasks.

`mro` ([method-resolution-order in python](https://www.python.org/download/releases/2.3/mro/)) is a built-in attribute of python's `object` class, which defines the order of initialization of the objects in scenarios of multiple inheritance.

`dask` find the `simulation` object in the dependency path, and therefore checks for its `mro` to figure out the correct order of initialization.

For some reason, on my windows version, `__mro__` atrribute is not required, but it is on linux.

Using a direct inheritance from `object` will create this attribute, and solve the problem:

```
class simulation(object):
   # defines simulation parameters
   def __init__(self,x):
        self.x = x
```

Answer (score 2):

Your example actually works just fine for me on Linux, both with Python 2.7 and 3.6.

However as you note in your comment I suspect that your issue is with this line:

```
class simulation():
```

This is odd, typically you see one of the following in Python 2.7

```
class simulation(object):  # new style class
class simulation:  # old style class
```

I recommend trying one of these and see if that resolves your problem.